# Нужно подсчитать строки с одинаковыми буквами

Tags: java, строки

```
    public class Main3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
         int sum = 0;
         String t = "aaabbbzzbbaaaaccczbbbbb";
            String [] s = t.split("");
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                sum = sum + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
```

нужный результат
a=2;
b=3;
z=2;
c=1;

Comment: начни здесь - [ask]. А еще лучше посмотри что твой код делает. Как это вообще связано с задачей?

Comment: Если в лоб, то Map<String,int> для хранения результатов, переменная для хранения текущего символа и при каждой смене символов увеличение соответствующего счётчика в "мапе".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это достаточно стандартная задача на построение мапы частот букв в строке, при этом повторяющиеся буквы должны быть удалены, т.е. `"aaa" -> 'a', "bbb" -> 'b'` и т.д.

Достаточно простое решение с использованием циклов и метода `Map::merge` для вычисления частоты:

- взять символ строки по текущему индексу, инкрементировать счетчик в мапе
- пропустить все дублирующие символы

```java
Map<Character, Integer> f = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0, n = t.length(); i < n; i++) {
    char c = t.charAt(i);
    f.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n && t.charAt(j) == c; j++) i++;
}
System.out.println(f);
```

Более лаконичный вариант с использованием `while`:

```java
for (int i = 0, n = t.length(); i < n;) {
    char c = t.charAt(i);
    f.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
    while (++i < n && c == t.charAt(i));
}
```

В любом случае для заданной строки `String t = "aaabbbzzbbaaaaccczbbbbb";` результат:

```
{a=2, b=3, z=2, c=1}
```

---

Также можно попытаться удалить дублированные символы при помощи `String::replaceAll` и затем строить обычную посимвольную мапу частот.

Решение с использованием Stream API:

```java
Map<Character, Integer> f2 = t.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1") // оставить первый символ
    .chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c) // IntStream
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        c -> c, LinkedHashMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(c -> 1)
    ));
System.out.println(f2);
// -> {a=2, b=3, z=2, c=1}
```